# Axios throwing 'Unexpected end of JSON input' error as opposed to Fetch in Next.JS 13.2 POST call

Tags: reactjs, next.js, axios, fetch

I've been looking into this quite a bit but I'm still baffled as to what's going on here. I have two functions, each essentially the same; Calling upon a POST method in my API. However, AXIOS throws a "Unexpected end of JSON input" error, where as Fetch does not. There are no changes to the API call upon using either AXIOS or Fetch.

Oddly enough, GET requests work just fine with AXIOS. It should also be noted that at one point while using the AXIOS call, I get a 'readablestream { locked: false, state: 'readable', supportsbyob: false }'. That dug me further into another rabbit hole.

Looking to see if anyone else had any insight?

FrontEnd:

```
// AXIOS 
    function handleSubmit(event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        var newBlog = {
            title: title,
            content: content,
        }

        axios.post('/api/blogs', JSON.stringify(newBlog))
        .then(response => {
            console.log(response.data);
        }).catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
        });
           
        // A different attempt at calling the POST method.
        // axios({
        //     url: '/api/blogs',
        //     method: "POST",
        //     headers: {
        //         "content-type": "application/json",
        //     },
        //     body: JSON.stringify({
        //         title: title,
        //         content: content,
        //     }),
        // }).then(response => {
        //     console.log(response.data);
        // }).catch(error => {
        //     console.log(error.data);
        // });
    }
// FETCH 
    async function handleSubmit2() {
        const postData = {
            method: "POST",
            headers: {
                "content-type": "application/json",
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                title: title,
                content: content,
            }),
        };
        const res = await fetch(`/api/blogs`, postData);
        const response = await res
        if (response.response.message !== "success") return;
    }
```

Backend:

```
export async function POST(req, res) {
    try {

        // In axios, this is where "SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input" occurs.
        const { title, content } = await req.json()


        const result = await executeQuery({ query: "INSERT INTO blogs (title, content, date) VALUES (?, ?, ?)", values: [title, content, new Date()] });

        const formattedResults = JSON.stringify(result);
        console.log(formattedResults)
        return formattedResults;
    } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error on create blog:", error);
        return false // res.status(500).send(formattedResults);
    }
}
```

db.jsx (where executeQuery resides)

```
import mysql from 'serverless-mysql';

const db = mysql({
    config: {
        host: process.env.DBHOST,
        port: process.env.DBPORT,
        database: process.env.DB,
        user: process.env.DBUSER,
        password: process.env.DBPASS
    }
});
export default async function executeQuery({ query, values }) {
    try {
        const results = await db.query(query, values);
        await db.end();
        return results;
    } catch (error) {
        return { error };
    }
}
```

When using the AXIOS call, I've tried changing the .json() to .text(), per other posts. Along with that, I've also tried multiple little iterations, trying to get it to work accordingly. But I've strayed so far away already, I thought I'd ask.

Comment: Same, I was just trying to call a jira api using next 13 api. I am always getting 
```
SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
```
Even when the get request works fine in postman

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per the axios docs: https://axios-http.com/docs/post_example, when making a post request you do not need to use JSON.stringify yourself on the payload. Axios does that for you. The issue here is likely that your request body is currently getting "double stringified" (once by you, and once
by Axios.) So try making your request like this instead:

```
axios.post('/api/blogs', newBlog)
```

Comment: More generally this applies to every request method with axios, you will never need to call json.stringify or json.parse yourself when dealing with json requests/responses.